# Python Stand Alone Script Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, syntaxerror

I'm pretty new to python, but I'm trying to transpose a time field
 for a set of data I'm working with in ArcMap. I changed the file locations and fields to my needs. However, when I try to run the script in the python window I get the error

> Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)

It seems like this is an error with importing arcpy, but I believe ArcMap contains ArcPy. Additionally, running just import arcpy in the scripting window works fine.

Here is the Code:

```
# Name: TransposeFields_Ex_02.py
# Description: Tranpose field names from column headers to values in one column
# Requirements: None

# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "H:\Users\bdf006\Desktop\GIS Review\Pittsburgh Roads\RoadsWithTime.gdb"

# Set local variables
inTable = "Pittsburgh_Roads_Counts"
# Specify fields to transpose
fieldsToTranspose = "1a;2a;3a;4a;5a;6a;7a;8a;9a;10a;11a;12p;1p;2p;3p;4p;5p;6p;7p;8p;9p;10p;11p;12a"
# Set a variable to store output feature class or table
outTable = "Pittsburgh_Roads_Counts_With_Timw"
# Set a variable to store time field name
transposedFieldName = "Transposed_Time"
# Set a variable to store value field name
valueFieldName = "Value"
# Specify attribute fields to be included in the output
attrFields = "Shape;Type"

# Execute TransposeTimeFields
arcpy.TransposeFields_management(inTable, fieldsToTranspose, outTable, transposedFieldName, valueFieldName, attrFields)
```

Comment: I'd add print statements to troubleshoot where the issue occurs.

Comment: Remove everything prior to import arcpy

Comment: Why do you have `from arcpy import env`?  I would dispense with it.  Are you really using ArcGIS 10.0?

Comment: I suspect you have a strange line terminator/ escape sequence in the file. If Python complains about line 1, you don't need to provide more than the first non-comment. Line 10 contains a serious error -- The missing raw formatting flag `path = r"C:\something"`

Comment: Line one is your # Name line.  Sounds like it errors out before import arcpy.